# Jump to matching bracket in Brackets?

Tags: brackets

Is there a way to jump to the matching brace / bracket in the text editor Brackets aka [Brackets.io](http://brackets.io)?

Brackets definitely does match braces - it highlights matches - but I can't find any feature to jump to the match, in menus or docs. In Sublime Text the keyboard shortcut for this is `ctrl-m`.

---

It's a tricky one to search on because every other text editor's docs pages for bracket / brace matching match the search term "Brackets"... I'm just getting pages and pages about bracket matching in every other text editor available.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the [Jump to Matching Brace extension](https://github.com/peterflynn/brackets-jump-to-matching) to add this functionality to Brackets.  (I'll add a note to the bug cited in the other answer).

The shortcut it uses is `Ctrl-Shift-[`, though you can use the [Key Remapper extension](https://bitbucket.org/sacah/brackets-key-remapper) to change it if you want.

Comment: I loved `CTRL + B` in Notepad++ because it works with non-English keyboards. Brackets' `Ctrl-Shift-[` does not work, especially not on German keyboards. Thanks for pointing out the extensions. @Brackets_dev: Just add the default `CTRL + B`.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that Brackets is partly supported by Adobe and so you can get some more relevant results by searching for `"Adobe Brackets"` in quotes.

Using this, I found [this issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/5462) which seems to suggest that jumping to matching bracket has been an open "to do" since Oct 2013 and (as of August 2014) hasn't been implemented yet.